# Autocorrelation function decay for AR(p), how to proof

Tags: time-series, arima, autocorrelation, autoregressive, arma

How can I demonstrate that the Autocorrelation function (ACF) for an AR(p) decay exponentially? It seems so simple but neither Enders' book nor Greene's has such proof.

Comment: Have you tried Brockwell and Davis?

Comment: See p. 24 in Cochrane's "Time Series for Macroeconomics and Finance": http://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/john.cochrane/research/papers/time_series_book.pdf